# How to make button with background image redirect to WebView React Native

Tags: react-native, webview

I have problem to make button with background image and then redirect to my WebView React Native.

I already have run code to show my web view, and I want before my web view show, its triggered from button click who look like this

[image: button with background image]

Below is the code for my WebView;

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'  
import {  

View,StyleSheet,AppRegistry  
} from 'react-native'  
import {WebView} from 'react-native-webview'  

export default class ActivityIndicatorDemo extends Component {  
    render() {  
        return (  
            <View style = {styles.container}>  
                {/*<WebView 
                    source={{html: '<h1>Hello javaTpoint</h1>'}} 
                />*/}  
             {/*   <WebView 
                    source={require("./resources/index.html")} 
                />*/}  
                <WebView  
                    // injectedJavaScript={false}
                    // javaScriptEnabled={false}
                    // originWhitelist={['*']}
                    source = {{ uri:'http://myip/login' }}  
                />  
            </View>  
        )  
    }  
}  
const styles = StyleSheet.create({  
    container: {  
        justifyContent: 'center',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        flex: 1,  
    }  
})  

AppRegistry.registerComponent('App', () => ActivityIndicatorDemo)
```

How I can implement button with background image before my WebView shows?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to do it.

```
    import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {
  View,
  ImageBackground,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Text,
  StatusBar,
} from 'react-native';

import WebView from "react-native-webview";
const App = () => {
  const [visible, showWebview] = useState(false)

  const setVisible = (visible) => {
    showWebview(visible);
  }
  return (
    <View
    style={{
      width:'100%',
      height:"100%"
    }}
    >
      {
        !visible? <View
        style={{
          width:'100%',
          height:"100%"
        }}
        > <ImageBackground
        source={{uri:"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1556742031-c6961e8560b0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&dl=clay-banks-tgquMvhNLc4-unsplash.jpg"}}
        style={{width:"100%",height:"90%",zIndex:999,justifyContent:"center",alignItems:"center"}}

       /> <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => setVisible(true)}
          style={{
            backgroundColor:"white",
            justifyContent:"center",
            alignItems:"center",
            padding:10,height:"10%"
          }}
          >
            <Text>Show Webview</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>  </View> : 
        <View
        style={{
          flex:1
        }}
        >
           <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => setVisible(false)}
          style={{
            backgroundColor:"red",
            padding:10,
            justifyContent:'center',
            alignItems:'center',
            width:"100%"
          }}
          >
            <Text style={{color:'white'}} >Hide Webview</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
           <WebView 
    scalesPageToFit
      originWhitelist={["*"]} 
      source={{ uri:"https://www.google.com"

     }}/>

        </View>

      }







    </View>
  );
};



export default App;
```

Comment: hi, thank you very much for helping me, but where i can place my image? on your code source={require("./tests//image.jpg")} , i dont now that place @ammarahmed

Comment: put the image in yourprojectname/src/assets/images/ then add its path relative to the location of the file in which you put the above code.

Comment: try the above code again. I have changed the path to an online image url

Comment: thanks its work!, you really kind, thankyou so much

Comment: but how i can put my button on bottom of image, not inside image?

Comment: Try the code again, I have changed it to allow button to show on bottom. If you find my answer useful please upvote it.

Comment: thats error given like Device: (101:391) Invariant Violation: Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component.

Comment: I have fixed it now. it will work properly now. check again